# UTF-8 format with twitter data in pandas

Tags: string, pandas, utf-8, tweepy

I am sorry if I don't have the best example (or one at all) here but I have a large data frame of approximately 1000 rows of tweets from twitter.

I'd like to be able to use this, but I run into issues with the formatting of symbols and what not.  I already have everything in the data frame and I don't want to re-run my code that gathered it.  Is there someway to easily strip out all the abnormal text characters and symbols and special characters from ALL columns?

Comment: Use `.apply` and some of the numerous Python string functions if what you want to do is not available in the pandas `.str` class.

Comment: Could you share the first 5 rows of the dataframe so that we can estimate the type of chars present in the entire frame?